# How to load a tsv file for MALLET using FileInputStream in Java?

Tags: java, csv, fileinputstream, mallet, inputstreamreader

I want to load the flat text file passed in as 'TMFlatFile' (which is the .tsv file format to use in MALLET) into into the fileReader variable.
I have created the method, RunTopicModelling() and  am having a problem with the try/except block.
I have created my File and FileInputStream objects, but dont know how to load it correctly into fileReader?

I have an error that "The method read(CharBuffer) in the type InputStreamReader is not applicable for the arguments (int)".

```
public class TopicModelling {
    
    private void StartTopicModellingProcess(String filePath) {
        JSONIOHelper jsonIO = new JSONIOHelper(); 
        jsonIO.LoadJSON(filePath); 
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> lemmas = jsonIO.GetDocumentsFromJSONStructure();
        
        
        SaveLemmaDataToFile("topicdata.txt" ,lemmas);
        
    }
    
    private void SaveLemmaDataToFile(String TMFlatFile, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> lemmas) {

        for (Entry<String, String> entry : lemmas.entrySet()) {
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(TMFlatFile)) {
                ;
                writer.write(entry.getKey() + "\ten\t" + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");
            } catch (Exception e)

            {
                System.out.println("Saving to flat text file failed...");

            }
        }
    }

    private void RunTopicModelling(String TMFlatFile, int numTopics, int numThreads, int numIterations) {
         ArrayList<Pipe> pipeList = new ArrayList <Pipe>();

         // Pipes: tokenise, map to features
        pipeList.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence (Pattern.compile("\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")));
        pipeList.add(new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence());
        
        InstanceList instances = new InstanceList (new SerialPipes(pipeList)); 
        
        
        InputStreamReader fileReader = null;
        //loads the file passed in via the TMFlatFile variable into the fileReader variable - this block I have a problem with
        try {
        
            File inFile = new File(TMFlatFile);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        

            int line;
            
            while ((line = fis.read()) != -1) {
                }
                fileReader.read(line);

                
            } 
        fis.close();
        }catch(

    Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Load Failed");
        System.exit(1);

    }
\\      // linking data to the pipeline
        instances.addThruPipe(new CsvIterator(fileReader,Pattern.compile("^(\\S*)[\\s,]*(\\S*)[\\s,]*(.*)$"),3,2,1));
    
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what the immediate issue is because the code sample provided looks like it's missing important parts, and would not compile as written (for example `Exception e)` and regex without quotes).

The data import developers guide https://mimno.github.io/Mallet/import-devel has sample code that should be a good starting point.

Comment: thanks for the link, David.  I have added the quotes into regex.   problem is with this try/except block.